# Entity Framework 4.1 default eager loading

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, eager-loading

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 code first approach.

I want to make eager loading as my the dafault configuration, and by that avoid using the Include extension method in each fetching query.

I did as recomended in MSDN, changing the simple lazy property at the DbContext constructor:

```
public class EMarketContext : DbContext
{
    public EMarketContext()
    {
        // Change the default lazy loading to eager loading
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    }
}
```

unfortunately, this approach is not working. I have to use the Include method to perform eager loading in each query. Any ideas why?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26):

There is no default configuration for eager loading. You must always define `Include` or create some reusable method which will wrap adding include. For example you can place similar method to your context:

```
public IQueryable<MyEntity> GetMyEntities()
{
    return this.MyEntities.Include(e => e.SomeOtherEntities);
}
```

Comment: According to the ADO.Net developers, you're wrong. check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Comment: No I'm not wrong. I know this article and there is not any part which would describe "permanent `Include`"

Comment: please look at (in the middle) : "Turn off lazy loading for all entities".

Comment: But it doesn't change lazy loading to eager loading. It just turns off lazy loading. Eager loading is still manual operation performed by `Include`

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - Include will only eager load one projection. What if you need to eager load further? .Include( entity => entity.FirstCollection.Select( fc => fc.FirstProjection.Select( **this projection fails to generate a properly defined SQL statement** )))

Comment: I won't even dare to argue a 218K user :)