# Is it possible to load the whole entity without includes?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Can EF automatically (without Includes) load the whole graph if it doesn't have cycles?

Comment: What's the objection to includes?

Comment: Need to write it manually for each entity....or...we can generate the queries with T4...Hum, I'll think about this.

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042023/entity-framework-4-1-default-eager-loading and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232, as stated by others, there is no way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to achieve this, either explicitly specify the data to be loaded using `Include` or allow Lazy Loading to load related entities on demand.