# Lazy loading One-To-One relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, one-to-one

I'm working on a website using Asp.Net MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6. I'm trying to add a One-To-One relationship between `ApplicaitonUser` and `UserBalance` entities. Here's the 2 classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual UserBalance Balance { get; set; }
}

public class UserBalance
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

When I load the users from database the Entity Framework loads an empty `UserBalance` and I can't save the changes. I have to use `.Include("Balance")` to load the information.

How can I make the Entity Framework automatically load the balance information from the database without the need of the `Include` function?

#### Update:

This is how I retrieve the user which returns the user **without** the `Balance`.

```
var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
```

This is how I retrieve it **with** the `Balance`:

```
var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = await db.Users.Include("Balance").FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userid);
```

Comment: Could you show how you retrieve the data?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917423/entity-framework-eager-load-not-returning-data-lazy-load-does).

Comment: @Win see the update.

Comment: Where have you configured the relationship?  I don't see any annotations nor ModelBuilder code?

Comment: @SteveGreene I checked the link. The lazy loading is enabled for my context. I use it for other parts of even the same entity (`ApplicationUser`). The `virtual` modifier is there too. Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: @ErikPhilips EF should know I'm looking for a 1-to-1-or-0 relationship because there's a `RequiredAttribute` for the `ApplicationUser` of `UserBalance`. Either way I tried adding the code explicitly with the fluent API. It didn't help.

Comment: If you don't configure it, it doesn't just magically know the relationship...

Comment: Actually, EF can establish relationships via [convention](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04.html).

Comment: Yes, you have [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) properly configured, but you need the Include() regardless as Gert points out.

Comment: @SteveGreene but why does it work for some entities and not for others? Also I used to retrieve the data using `Include` but I want to use `userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync` and it throws an exception because of this.